# Having some issues with Ubuntu 16.10, things crashing, etc

Tags: nvidia, hardware, 16.10

I'm starting to feel a little lost at the moment. I'm trying to get away from macOS because Apple have destroyed the MacBook line with their latest offerings, so I've been setting up Ubuntu again.

I've had 16.10 running now for a short while, and I've just dealt with the random issues, but it's just starting to really get on my nerves now.

1. Sometimes USB devices just randomly stop working. Unplugging them and re-inserting them resolves the issue.
2. Chrome... oh my god Chrome. Randomly crashes (apparently a segfault). The performance is also terrible - resizing Chrome is incredibly slow (I've changed it so it only redraws the window when you finish resizing, rather than whilst your resize).
3. Random processes seem to randomly crash. I just get the error reporting tools pop up every so often.
4. For some reason, lightdm takes ages to start up, I get past the boot screen and sit there for about 10 seconds while lightdm decides what it's trying to do.

All the while, I dual boot with Windows 10 - and that's working flawlessly. None of the issues above. Because of the segfaults I ran memtest, it was totally clear. I've primed my CPU in Windows as well as I have a slight overclock, and that was stable after a good 12 hours of priming. All of it seems to point to some weird issues in Linux - and I can't for the life in me figure out what on earth is going on!

I tried 16.04 a little while ago, but had a lot of trouble with the setup because I have an new Pascal Nvidia card, I thought it was supposed to work with 16.04.1 though...

Here's my main pieces of hardware:

- Intel Core i5 3570k (OC is just at 4.0Ghz)
- 2x Kingston HyperX Beast 8GB 2133 Mhz RAM
- Gigabyte GA-Z77X-D3H
- Nvidia (Gigabyte) GTX 1070 Windforce OC (using nvidia-375 drivers from the graphics-drivers PPA)
- 500GB Samsung Evo 850

I suppose a couple of other potentially relevant bits (USB devices):

- Ducky One TKL RGB Keyboard
- Razer Deathadder Chroma
- Blue Snowball iCE
- Asus USB-BT400 bluetooth adapter

Is this all just because of Ubuntu 16.10 being unstable? Should I persist with Ubuntu 16.04 again? Is my hardware incompatible with Linux at the moment?

Comment: You have newer graphics card that needs proprietary drivers. I don't see any mentions of those so I'm assuming you're running the default open source driver.

Comment: I'm running nvidia-375 currently.

Comment: OK, that *should* work with GTX1070. Please edit and add that information as it may be important.